# Configurable Product Not Showing Up on Search - Out of Stock Magento 1.9

Tags: magento-1.9, search, catalogsearch, out-of-stock

I'm having trouble with Magento 1.9 where out-of-stock products aren't showing up in searches or the product list. Here's what I've tried:

- The products are correctly assigned to the appropriate website and categories.
- I've attempted to display out-of-stock configurable products by disassociating all associated simple products, but they still don't appear.
- I've verified that Elastisearch settings are correct, and the configuration to display out-of-stock items is properly configured.
- Even when I manually change the product status to "in stock," it doesn't show up.
- I've confirmed that they have the necessary adjustments (enabled, catalog/search).
- Cache has been cleared, and I've reindexed everything.

Interestingly, the product does appear when accessed via a direct link, but it's not showing up in search results.

I'm unsure what might be causing this issue. I've attempted to configure it similarly to other items that do appear in search, but they still don't show up. These products were disabled for some time, and now I'm unable to leave them live on search and listing while out of stock. Any assistance would be greatly appreciated.